# Vue 3 Installation Hanged

Tags: npm, vuejs3, vue-cli

I'm new to vuejs and I went to their documentation to install it for the first time using

```
`npm install -g @vue/cli`.
```

I have chosen the manual installation and I'm almost done. Suddenly, the installation just hanged for hours now.

[image: Installation process hanged.]

Comment: Hours? Hit ctrl-c and try the command again.

Comment: I created a new vue project with `vue create form-handling` and I am using windows 10

Comment: It has been resolved. I used powershell as an admin to install the vue-cli and I re-created the vue project.